# Why standard library function of a constexpr is not a constant?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

```
constexpr PixelType maxVal = std::numeric_limits<PixelType>::max();
constexpr double lnFactor = std::log(maxVal);
```

Second line gives error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant

Why? Can this be rephrased so it compiles?

Comment: `std::log` is not `constexpr`

Comment: There are many ways to calculate logarithms, but not all of them can be easily done at time of compilation (which is the basic premise behind `constexpr`). Since the C++ standard can not force library writers to use variants that can be evaluated at compile time, it can't be turned into a `constexpr` function. So you simply can't use it to calculate logarithms at compile-time.

Comment: Does MSVC have a compiler intrinsics for it? (....) https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/3k897k/constexpr_of_natural_log_in_c11/  https://hbfs.wordpress.com/2016/03/22/log2-with-c-metaprogramming/

Comment: Maybe you can use this: If `PixelType` is an unsigned integral type, `log(maxVal + 1) == log(2) * <PixelType bitcount>`, or approximately `0.69314718056 * sizeof(PixelType) * 8`.

Comment: That's a good and easy alternative @ChristopherOicles

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get a compile error is that [`std::log`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log) is not `constexpr`.

I am not aware of a portable way to make it work with `constexpr`, but GCC has `__builtin_log` that works in `constexpr` context ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/bvmuW6)):

```
constexpr double lnFactor = __builtin_log(42.0);
```